# Firebird database replication

Tags: database, replication, firebird

I have reached the point where I've decided to replace my custom-built replication system with a system that has been built by someone else, mainly for reliability purposes. Can anyone recommend any replication system that is worth it? Is [FiBRE](http://fibre.sourceforge.net) any good?

What I need might be a little away from a generic system, though. I have five departments with each having it's own copy of the database, and the master in a remote location. The departments all have sporadic internet connection, the master is always online. The data has to flow back and forth from the master, meaning that all departments need to be equal to the master (when internet connection is available), and to upload changes made during network outage that are later distributed to other departments by the master.

Comment: See also: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq249/ , https://www.ib-aid.com/en/distributed-firebird-asynchronous-replication , https://www.ibphoenix.com/products/software/avalerion , https://habr.com/ru/post/117917/ ,  https://www.ibase.ru/d_repl/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used CopyCat to create a replication project.  It allows you create your own replication client/server configuration using CodeGear Delphi.   This allows you complete flexibilty as to how you want your replication to work.

If you don't use Delphi, or need a prefabricated solution, CopyTiger does the same thing already configured.

Answer (score 3):

I find IBReplicator by IBPhoenix to be the most complete, but there are many more listed here (with short descriptions):

http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq249/

Answer (score 1):

The Ibphoenix site list replication tools

[IbPhoenix Replication Tools](http://www.ibphoenix.com/download/tools/replication)