# How to sync my Local Firebird Database with another Firebird Database?

Tags: firebird

First of all i read this question:
[Firebird database replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929/firebird-database-replication)

But i dont want to replicate...i just want to add the data that had changed on my database to our main database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAICT that's replication too.

Comment: Yup, it's called one-way replication.

Answer (score 1):

You should mark every change of your database and at one time read them and pass them to your other database.

You can mark each record with a logical value Modified=0/1 or with a TimeStamp.

Through triggers you should control this values

```
trigger before insert
begin
   modified = CurrentDateTime;
end

trigger before ubdate
begin
   modified = CurrentDateTime;
end

trigger before delete
begin
   insert into DELETED_RECORDS (id) values (old.id);
end
```